# Sharepoint postgresql data connection

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

We are migrating our intranet to SharePoint and our previous system used `postgresql` so I'm trying to make it work with SharePoint, which is not easy.

I tried to add a data source on SharePoint designer and installed ODBC (psqlODBC) and OLEDB (PGNP) drivers but even with that I get errors on SharePoint designer (images below).

Also the funny part is that on the SharePoint server I'm able to connect through excel using the OLEDB provider I installed.
[image]

[image]

[image]

The error I get when looking into SharePoint logs are listed below and happen during two POSTS (the domain for security reasons is not that one)`(POST:https://sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/webpartpages.asmx:GetXmlDataFromDataSource)`:

```
05/21/2016 18:08:13.24  w3wp.exe (0x2714)   0x3D04  SharePoint Foundation   Claims Authentication   a1n25   High    Token is for a windows account. e3827e9d-0814-1066-3883-8cc161d0f500
05/21/2016 18:08:13.26  w3wp.exe (0x2714)   0x3D04  SharePoint Foundation   Claims Authentication   a5rig   High    User key is not an encoded claim. UserKey: '            '.  e3827e9d-0814-1066-3883-8cc161d0f500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is how I fixed the issue.**

Sharepoint won't give the option to select the appropriated external data source driver unless you install layer2solutions:

www.layer2solutions.com (this is not free)

This will give you a new link called "Connect to external data source" on all list settings page which then allows you to select the the ".Net data provider for Postegresql" and using the below connection string you are able to connect to PostgreSQL.

User ID=user;Password=password;Host=postgresql_host_ip;Port=5432;Database=database_name;

As the data provider I used [npgsql](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases).
(download the msi installer).

1. Install npgsql
2. Install layer2solutions
3. Add a list in sharepoint
4. Go to list settings
5. Click "Connect external data source"
6. Use the connection string with your DB settings
7. Save the settings
8. In order to create new List Items in Sharepoint the ID (primary key) in Postgresql table needs to have a default serial value otherwise you'll get a "not null" error.